# Entity Framework 7 and login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to work with ef7 and asp.net mvc 6, but when i try to work with db there comes following exceptions:

> Cannot open database "Posts" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'alexpc\Alexandr'.

In DbContext class  i use following code:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=alexpc;Database=Posts;Integrated security=True;");
}
```

It seems like ConnectionString is right, where can there be the problem?

Comment: When "Integrated security" is set to true, it uses the current windows logon identity to access sql server. That happened to be 'alexpc\Alexandr' in your environment and it did not have permission to access sql. Either change the connection string to use a sql login, or configure sql server to allow 'alexpc\Alexandr' to login.

Comment: ... Windows user Alexandr does not have rights to open a connection to database Posts?

Comment: @ken2k no, Alexandr does have rights to open a connection to database Posts, i can succesfully connect with management studio and visual studio tools, but not with ef.

Comment: @Vince i tried to use connectionstring with login and password, but had the same exception.

Comment: some addition: the same connectionstring perfectly works in ef6. Now i do not understand anything, where can be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is solved in this way: It turned out, that the exception "Login failed for user "Username"" raised, when before the first launch migration was not made by the hand. It automatically worked for "Code First" in the EF6, but in EF7 this feature was off.
To perform migration you need a DNVM, which you can install using guide from this page: https://github.com/aspnet/home 
Then you need to open command prompt and change directory to your project (where "project.json" file is located ) and type the following commands:

```
dnx . ef migration add
dnx . ef migration apply
```

If you did everything right,  "Migration" folder must appear in your project directory. Now you can run your project without this exception!

Comment: I was hoping things will be easier to do with the new version. Why using command prompts? Package manager console was working just fine..

Comment: couldn't agree more @renakre.  this seems convoluted.  not to mention, new projects out of the box don't work?

Comment: @Keith I tried to work with ASP.NET 5 for 1 week, but then gave up, toooo many problems! I guess it is wise not to build something with it until the final version is released.